# Vue and firestore data binding

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve data from firestore and bind them to the vue data.

I retrieve the firestore data in the following manner in the created lifecycle hook:

```
  created(){

console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);
const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc("VezLOaumLCza8jih8Ylk");
docRef.get().then(
  function(doc){
    if(doc.exists){
      console.log(`Document data: ${doc.data()}`);
      this.user = doc.data();
    } else {
      console.log(`Doc data is undefined`);
    }
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log(`Oops: ${err.message}`);
  });
}
```

The issue is that `this` does not refer to the vue instance, in fact `this` is undefined at the point where I'm trying to set the user variable. How can I bind the user data to the vue data? It seems I'm missing something and I can't figure out what might be the issue.

The ultimate goal is to have a form which allows the user to modify his/her data.

(printing out the doc.data() gives the expected results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `then` callback is a separate function, therefore when `this` is accessed inside of that function, it is referencing the `then` callback. You need to create a reference to the Vue VM prior to the `then` callback.

Try this:

```
created(){

console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);
const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc("VezLOaumLCza8jih8Ylk");
var vm = this; //creating the reference to the Vue VM.
docRef.get().then(
  function(doc){
    if(doc.exists){
      console.log(`Document data: ${doc.data()}`);
      vm.user = doc.data();
    } else {
      console.log(`Doc data is undefined`);
    }
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log(`Oops: ${err.message}`);
  });
}
```

Comment: This seems to work and also makes sense. I wrongfully believed the this would still refer to the vue instance. Thanks for the quick answer.